# Sync remote data between host app and widget on iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, today-extension

In my app I have data that I fetch from the internet and display inside my app. I store this data inside a CoreData database.
This data will be updated about every 30 minutes.

Now I want to add a widget for my app and am thinking about how I best sync the data between the widget and the main app.

**Solution 1**.: Move the CoreData database to the shared app space and read the data from there. Not sync with the widget and hope that the background fetch of the main app is activated and is happening often enough. But I guess that's the worst solution as data will most of the time not be up to date...

**Solution 2**.: Move the CoreData database to the shared app space and read the data from there. But since the data only updates when main app opens, I'd also need to fetch data inside the widget and store it to the database.
This brings several problem. First being potential simultaneous writes to the same database. Second being the NSManagedObjectContext of the main app not reflecting any changes made my the widget f.e.
So... not ideal?!?

**Solution 3**.: Have the widget have it's own copy of the data. But since I want to have about 2-3 widgets, the user would then potentially make senseless syncs just to have several copies of the data. But at least I guess this solution would be the one with the fewest potential conflicts?

I am wondering what you guys would suggest. I've read a bit about it on the internet but haven't found a cool solution yet. So I am looking for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: 
Host app <=> message brokers(MQTT) <=> IOS app.

This solution will create realtime data.